# insert array of objects into table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have the following array:

```
arr = [{"a":1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}]
```

Using some help from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array), I am trying to parse these elements like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_arr2text_arr(_js JSONB)
  RETURNS text[] AS
  $func$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(_js));
$func$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

This returns:

```
"{{""a"": 1, ""b"": 2},{""a"": 1, ""b"": 3}}"
```

Now I want to insert these values into a table, couple with 2 `fkeys` with each row insert:

```
FOR LOOP OVER ARR:
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (DEFAULT, somefkeyvalue, arr[i].a, arr[i].b);
```

How would I go about writing the above `query` to the real thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr` is a json array. right?
Using `jsonb_array_elements` expand it into a set of jsonb values. More json arrays in your particular example. Sort of unnest json array.
And then use reference (`->` operator) to 'a' and 'b' keys to obtain your insert values.

Something like

```
INSERT INTO table (somefk, a_value, b_value)
SELECT
  'somefk',
  datajson->'a',
  datajson->'b'
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"a":1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}]'::jsonb) AS t(datajson)
```

Comment: I don't understand what should I need to actually do
.? I have my NodeJS server which saves data into my table. I sent my array of objects but it returns me in another format (combination of ///""). Please someone help me doing this.